# What are some examples of thread-unsafe Python code?

Tags: python

What are some examples of Python code that is not safe to run in a threaded environment? Examples need not be framework-related -- simple Python examples and caveats are preferred. Thanks!

Comment: SO is for specific programming questions. There is an infinite amount of code that can display thread un-safety. Do you have a more specific question you could ask?

Answer (score 3):

The following function may write to the file / overwrite the file in an unpredictable way.

```
 import threading

 fp = open('f','w')

 def work1():
     for x in range(10000):
         fp.write('1')
 def work2():
     for x in range(10000):
         fp.write('2')

 t1 = threading.Thread(target = work1)
 t1.daemon = True
 t2 = threading.Thread(target = work2)
 t2.daemon = True

 t1.start()
 t2.start()
 t1.join()
 t2.join()
```

On the other hand, the locking mechanism here will prevent the file output from getting mixed up.

```
 import threading
 lock = threading.Lock()

 fp = open('f','w')

 def work1():
     with lock:
         for x in range(10000):
             fp.write('1')
 def work2():
     with lock:
         for x in range(10000):
             fp.write('2')

 t1 = threading.Thread(target = work1)
 t1.daemon = True
 t2 = threading.Thread(target = work2)
 t2.daemon = True

 t1.start()
 t2.start()
 t1.join()
 t2.join()
```

Comment: That's not thread unsafe because each `fp.write()` will not be interrupted because of GIL

Comment: So it's implementation-dependent whether this code is thread safe or not? In that case it's a particularly good example, because you can develop on one platform, never get a multithread-related bug, and then not understand why your code works badly when you move it to another.